# Pros and Cons: Writing HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, design-patterns, web-standards

*(I'm using google translate)*

I separate my **HTML and PHP**, just for good programming practices in MVC.
However a lot of the time I come across someone on staff writing HTML directly in a PHP file.

And during the discussion of **'don't do that, it's bad, it's not a good practice'**, I haven't got any technical arguments, apart from 'it's not good practice'.

And they always say, 'I am not bound to get stuck on details."

Technically, because it isn't recommended?

Comment: I agree with you. So the template is also a PHP file ? Are you using any known MVC ?

Comment: People will argue a lot about this. The problem with having HTML and PHP mixed up is that it's hard to reuse the code, and often a lot harder to read and understand it. There are lots of ways to do it - Twig (as in Symfony) and HAML are at the extreme of separation. I think that only using HTML inside views, and restricting the PHP that's there to `if`, `for`, `foreach` separates things enough.

Comment: Without actually performing research on the topic, I don't think there is a difference in performance. To my knowledge, the only thing it will hurt is readability. It make it harder to read and understand your code when it jumps between HTML and PHP.

Comment: It is less confusing and more maintainable to have everything regarding the presentation in a defined place. Having a closer look, these are not technical arguments … and therefore subject of discussion. In a team with different opinions about organization and structure, then someone has to set the rules. And “it's not a good practice” is not a good argument indeed – there are definitely scenarios, where old style terrible one-file HTML-PHP-mixups are an absolutely sufficient design. It’s certainly a weakness, but definitely also a strength of PHP to allow both.

Comment: Yes, I always develop everything using MVC, so the question. I believe that HTML is the VIEW, the PHP the Controller/Model. I don't see logic in mixing / join both "layers / languages​​." Anyway, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not recommended because the past has shown that the longer a routine or script grows, the harder it is to manage. If you need to deal with HTML and PHP in one file, you need to write more than if you would have separated the code into two. Which brings me to the point that you write more in one file with HTML and PHP which results in more complex code.

This is only general. There are programmers out there who don't have a problem with larger code-chunks and who don't have a problem with mixing languages in the same files.

At first sight it might even look easier. However, as software tends to become more complex as it grows, after some time of growth it's worth to think about how to modularize the code, e.g. to separate the view from request processing.

One common line that is drawn between components is then between the output (display) and the processing. The processing will interface with the output layer then instead of having both jobs in one script/routine (processing and display of output). Actually the output is factually abstracted / normalized / reduced to make the output code work on it on it's own. E.g. instead of outputting HTML to the browser, the processing will pass objects to the output layer and the output layer will convert it into HTML then (the meaning of *object* is broad here, can be a variable, an array or an OOP object).

If you are developing together with someone else, you should decide together where to draw these lines so you can actually work together. You're both doing something wrong because like you write in your question it's not clear how you can work together. Working together is more crucial than favouring one design over the other. If you think your colleague is wrong, you both need to discuss the issue.

Comment: Just what I think about it. Every system must be designed aiming at the growth, maintenance, or simply the growth of the team. If everything is planned that way, the layers are best divided, and there will be an easier to find something. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you can think about it like this.

If the PHP-code is related to how the information is being displayed to the user, then it is OK to have it in the view (if you are using an MVC approach) or mixed in with the HTML. Sometimes you need small pieces of code to display the information as you want, "if this date is passed then show it like this, otherwise show it like that".

In any other case, you should avoid mixing your PHP with your HTML, for the purpose of structure, ease of maintenance, DRY and so on.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write. Congrats on your 2k rep mate :)

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I agree about your point, in some cases, in return for an error / validation is valid PHP + HTML together, but I still don't totally agree, I think, PHP should do their work only , since the HTML it. Anyway, you've done very well. Thank you.